# Генерация поля в Android

Tags: java, android

[image: Field]

Необходимо сделать генерацию поля, чтобы в одном рандомном элементе был цвет.

Как сделать генерацию такого поля размером X на X?

Величина "Х" может быть разной.

Comment: с чем конкретно проблема? как сгенерировать целое число в определенном диапазоне?

Comment: нет, число есть, то самое Х, я не знаю как сгенерировать поле размером Х на Х.

Comment: В цикле, разумеется. Что именно не получается в генерировании поля?

Comment: да не лень это, я целый день бьюсь над этой проблемой, решил сюда написать, а как в цикле?

Comment: Я пробовал через, TableLayout, но там я не смог рандомно выбрать элемент.

Comment: ну, раз пробовал, значит показывай, как пробовал.

Comment: @metalurgus Вот тут читал, и пользовался вторым примером, developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/tablelayout.php Но у меня не получились отступы, а они важны, и выбор рандомного элемента

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если взять код по ссылке в комментариях, то цвет выставляется так

```
tableRow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(my_random_color));
```

Что касается отступов, то нужно использовать TableLayout.LayoutParams
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.LayoutParams.html
вместо ViewGroup.LayoutParams, там и отступы можно будет задать.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, попробую.

Comment: Все получилось, за исключением отступов, отступы делал вот так:
'ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);' 
но после того как сделал, то вообще перестали появляться картинки.

Comment: LinearLayout это предок TableLayout, в Вашем случае любой из них подходит.   
А зачем Вы задаете картинкам точный размер 100х100 пикселей? Если Вы их маштабируете, но надо scaleType задавать   
setScaleType (ImageView.ScaleType scaleType)

Comment: И еще, LayoutParams лучше не задавать картинке напрямую, а добавлять ее в контейнер с этими параметрами. Есть такой метод у контейнеров addView (View child, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)

Comment: Спасибо, я просто не часто работаю с созданием чего либо программно, поэтому, как-то так, сейчас я уже со всем разобрался, ваши советы очень полезны)